# Html Regex pattern first digit [1,9] second digit [0,9]

Tags: regex, html, input

I want to make sure phone number is inserted with first digit between 1-9 and following digits can be from 0-9, but i want it in this format :
`199-999-9999`
I tried : `[1-9]{1}[0,9]{2}-[0,9]{3}-[0,9]{4}`

Comment: What did you see when you tried that? What didn't work?

Comment: You want it in a `199-999-9999` or (3-3-4 (number of digits)) format right?

Answer (score 1):

Seems you were on the right track. Instead of a comma, use a dash within the `[]` to specify the range. Here I have escaped the true dashes, just to be clear:

```
[1-9]{1}[0-9]{2}\-[0-9]{3}\-[0-9]{4}
```

Depending on your language, you might have to format the syntax a bit more...

Comment: It is not going to be in the format OP wants I think.. _199-999-9999_

Comment: Seems like it is ok. First value from 1-9, the rest from 0-9. So `555-555-5555` is OK, but `055-555-5555` is not.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using javascript try:

```
^[1-9]{1}[0-9]*$
```

You can test the site:

http://regexpal.com/